# Jenkins - Active choices from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Having a first play with Jenkins and trying to get an active choices parameter working using a groovy script but not having much luck. The parameter drop down is always empty when I run the build. My groovy script is as below:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def output = []

def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/information_schema', 'jenkins', 'password', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
String sqlString = "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;"
sql.eachRow(sqlString){ row ->  
    output.push(row[0])
}


return output
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a way to see the output from the groovy script so I can see whether it is even making a connection to the database?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions

Comment: use a print  `println "$row.colname"`

Comment: If you want to test it easily, just create a normal groovy script step and debug there. Then use the code in active choices step. I guess the problem here was that row is actually a map `["schema_name":<value>]`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

//describe the DB connection params
def db = [
        url:'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information_schema',
        user:'root',
        password:'',
        driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']

//New connection
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

def output = []
//query
String sqlString = "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata"
sql.eachRow(sqlString){ row ->
  output.push(row.schema_name)
}
//clean up
sql.close()
```

You may peek inside now if you like that:

```
//Check what's up
String[] dbs = output as String[]

println dbs
```

The output is something like this on my machine:

```
[information_schema, mysql, ******, performance_schema, sys]
```

If you cannot connect to the DB for a reason whatsoever then you will get an exception. More docs [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html).

Within your Jenkins pipeline you may use [ChoiceParameterDefinition](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ChoiceParameterDefinition.html). Something like this (DISCLAIMER - not tested):

```
stage('Ask DB') {

    echo "Collecting user input about the DB..."

    String[] dbs = ...;//collect DB-s here

    //define the choice
    userChoice = new ChoiceParameterDefinition('targetDB',
            dbs,//<-- Pass array here!
            'Choose wisely your DB!')

    def targetDB = input(
            id: 'target-db',
            message: 'What is the DB?',
            parameters: [userChoice])

    echo "Input collected, proceeding for DB [${targetDB}]"
  }
```

Comment: Using a `println` statement helps debug when you run you your groovy code via the **Manage Jenkins > Script Console** or the **Scriptler > Run a script** option. If you want output from the code running,in the system log, when **building a job** use: `import java.util.logging.Logger`
 `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger('hudson.WebAppMain')` 
`logger.info("Value of parameter is ${paramName}")`